# Gaussian surface question: arbitrary wire in a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauss-law

I have a question about the setup in the image below. For the wire with $Q+$, if I draw a Gaussian Cylinder that just encloses the wire (as shown), where $s_1$ is the top surface of the cylinder and $s_2$ is the bottom surface of the cylinder, my textbook says that since Gauss' law yields

\begin{equation}
\int_{s_1}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S} + \int_{s_2}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S} = 
\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}, \;\;\;\;\; (1)\end{equation}

this readily implies that

\begin{equation}
\int_{s_1}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{s_2}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S} = \frac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}  \;\;\;\;\; (2)
\end{equation}

because "the designation of 1 and 2 is interchangeable".

However, I don't quite understand what is meant by this phrase, and/or how the symmetry of the problem allows one to assume Eqn. (2) from Eqn. (1). Can someone please illuminate what is being done here?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "the designation of 1 and 2 is interchangeable" it means the flux passing through the upper surface equals the flux passing through the lower surface.

In more details, because your system has reflection symmetry about the $xy$ plane and $E$ field is a vector, $\textbf{E}(x,y,-z)$ should be the mirror image of $\textbf{E}(x,y,z)$. Hence

$$\textbf{E}_z(x,y,z)=-\textbf{E}_z(x,y,-z)$$.

Comment: Could you please comment more on how we know the reflection symmetry implies the relationship you have written?

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by "should be the mirror image", how does this show up mathematically/rigorously?

Comment: Oh, I think I actually get it now, but if you could still explain some more that would be great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Gauss's law says that the total flux is given by equation 1. Equation 2 says that the flux exiting the top surface is equal to the flux exiting the bottom surface, and furthermore, they are each equal to half of the total. This makes sense since the system is symmetrical in the z-axis, as @AlphaGo says.